# Rendering a new view when a button is clicked

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am a noob with Sencha 2 and I am trying to find a way to render a new view when a button is clicked. Specifically, I have this view called Home

**Home**

```
Ext.define("Blog.view.Home", {
  extend:'Ext.Panel',
  xtype:'homepanel',


  config:{
    iconCls:"home",
    title:"Home",
    items:[
      {
        defaults:{
          iconMask:true
        },
        xtype:'toolbar',
        title:'Recent Blogs',
        docked:'top',
        items:[
          {
            id:'newBlog',
            xtype:'button',
            iconCls:'add',
            handler:function () {
              //What do I do here?
            }
          }
        ]
      },

      {
        html:"Recent Blogs"
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

And I want that button, when clicked, to render a new view. I am just not sure how I would do such thing. Can someone give me some pointer? Is this the best way to do this? Should I move this to my controller? If yes, what event should I listen to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I do it (i'm also learning) is defining the property 'action' of my button, for example:

```
{
  xtype: 'button'
  action: 'doSomething',
}
```

and handling the event in the control configuration of my controller:

```
control: {
  'button[action=doSomething]' : {
     tap: function() {
       getMainView().push(...);
     }
 }
```

in the handler you can push a new view if you are using the [NavigationView](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View) or add a new view to the [ViewPort](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Viewport) directly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: is getMainView() a generated method? I can't seem to use it.

Comment: @denniss I'm having the same getMainView() problem.  How did u solve it?

Comment: This is so great. I wish the action button was documented. I couldn't find it in the sencha touch documentation.

Answer (score 4):

The best practice to do this in Sencha Touch 2 (which follows MVC pattern) is to define a reference to your button and stick a control function to it in your controller. For example:

```
refs:{
button_which_renders_a_new_view: '#newBlog' //create a reference to your button

control: {
button_which_renders_a_new_view: 'create_a_new_view'
}

create_a_new_view: {
// do whatever you want here
}
```

For more details, let's take a deeper look at this: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller

Comment: the most simple way is just create a simple panel inside the create_a_new_view function like this: `create_a_new_view: {Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{html:'my panel'});}`